# Can I write a Select query to update the data too

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Can I write a Select query under a jdbc connection ,having a resultset object and which would update the records on just passing the select query them in my sql.

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want any change to the "resultset object" to be written back to the database automatically? Or are you looking for a SQL UPDATE statement that also returns a resultset of the changed rows?

Comment: you are right. I want change to the "resultset object" to be written back to the database automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, at least not with plain JDBC.

But, an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) might give you what you are looking for. However, the use of ORMs is controversial. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452385/what-java-orm-do-you-prefer-and-why for an interesting collection of opinions. You can find a few example ORMs in there too.